# JQuery location.reload(); preventing POST to database

Tags: jquery

The purpose of the code below is to add a new entry into a DB. Without the location.reload(true); it works fine. However, I would like to reload the page. Including the location.reload(true); line stops the new entry being added. Does anybody have any ideas? Is the reload happening before the POST request gets a chance to do its business? Remember: It works 100% fine without that one line.

```
$('#submitNewLocationButton').click(function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4)
        {
            if(xhr.status == 200)
        {
            document.ajax.dyn.value = "Received: " + xhr.responseText;
        }
        else
        {
            document.ajax.dyn.value = "Error code: " + xhr.status;
        }
        }
    };

    var param0 = "city=" + $('input[id=newRowCellInput_0]').val();
    var param1 = "extension=" + $('input[id=newRowCellInput_1]').val();

    xhr.open("POST", "insert.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(param0 + "&" + param1);

    $('#newRow').remove();
    $('#addNewLocationButton').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#submitNewLocationButton').css('display', 'none');
    location.reload(true);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, use `onload` event of `XMLHttpRequest`

```
xhr.onload = function () {
     location.reload(true);
};
```

or you can use

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
  location.reload(true);
};
```

Both are same `onload` was added in `XMLHttpRequest 2` whereas `onreadystatechange` has been around since the original spec.

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated? 
With jQuery you could achieve your goals in more simple ways
Try this:

```
$.post("insert.php?"+$(form).serialize())
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        location.reload(true);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("Error!");
    });
```

Anyways take a look to the [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)